# Getting gateway time-out Rails app with Nginx + Puma running on Digital Ocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, server-sent-events, puma

Following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma) I setup my app on a Digital Ocean droplet, but it is not working. The site is not loading and it's throwing: "Gateway time-out".

The Puma server works, since `ps aux | grep puma` prints:

```
root     15878  0.0  0.4 376832  2168 ?        Sl   12:50   0:00 puma 2.13.4 (unix:///var/www/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/myapp-puma.sock) [20150930164940]        
root     15881  0.0  0.7 903676  3692 ?        Sl   12:50   0:06 puma: cluster worker 0: 15878 [20150930164940]                                              
root     24654  0.0  0.1  11748   916 pts/2    S+   18:00   0:00 grep --color=auto puma
```

My Nginx config:

```
user root;

worker_processes 1;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    upstream puma {
       server unix:///var/www/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/myapp-puma.sock;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name myapp.com;
        root /var/www/myapp/current/public;
        access_log /var/www/myapp/current/log/access.log;
        error_log /var/www/myapp/current/log/error.log;

        try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
        location @puma {
            proxy_pass http://puma;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }

        client_max_body_size 10M;
        keepalive_timeout 10;
    }
}
```

I got no response from the server. In my `error.log` I have this error:

```
015/09/30 17:02:39 [error] 23840#0: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.47.218.12, server: myapp.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/www/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/myapp-puma.sock/", host: "myapp.com"
```

While `puma.error.log` is empty, `puma.access.log` contains:

```
message type 0x32 arrived from server while idle
message type 0x32 arrived from server while idle
message type 0x54 arrived from server while idle
message type 0x44 arrived from server while idle
message type 0x43 arrived from server while idle
message type 0x5a arrived from server while idle
message type 0x32 arrived from server while idle
message type 0x54 arrived from server while idle
message type 0x44 arrived from server while idle
message type 0x43 arrived from server while idle
message type 0x5a arrived from server while idle
message type 0x54 arrived from server while idle
message type 0x44 arrived from server while idle
message type 0x43 arrived from server while idle
message type 0x5a arrived from server while idle
```

From the main page my application starts listening server-sent events which is provided by PostgreSQL NOTIFY/LISTEN + ActionController::Live

Comment: please show me  `config/puma.rb`

Comment: If you no include `myapp.com` in your `/etc/hosts` with custom rule, you change server_name to localhost